# Bootstrap collapse menu/dropdown menu color question

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon! I'm currently working on a navbar but the menu that pops up on from clicking on the hamburger icon (which shows all the links/navigation-items as a  smaller screen widths) is a little too gaudy/not really good on a presentation level. How can I customize that dropdown menu to look better? HTML code is below:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
  <button id="hamburger-icon" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collap-menu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="D:\code\yannijewelry\images\evileyepng.png"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="collap-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Etsy</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What element do I target,  or rather, how can I customize a better dropdown menu? I noticed the hamburger icon, when clicked, also pushes the navbar elements up when it shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to know exactly how to advise you on styling since we can't see exactly what styles you're currently viewing with just the HTML. Utilizing the core Bootstrap CSS, I can approximate your view and advise accordingly.

Let's say you want to change the background and text color of each of your menu items:

```
#collap-menu li{
  background: #666;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#collap-menu li a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

This would set your menu items to a gray background with white text with a little additional spacing for the text. You can replace the colors here with the branding colors of your website. Any changes beyond changing the text and color would need to be specifically outlined in your request.